# How to make a nested div clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have some div buttons listed in a sidebar container and they worked fine but after I assigned a new div as their background and nested the buttons under it all the buttons lost their clickable functionality. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated.

```css
#sidebarContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  height: calc(99% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
}

.card2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 82%;
}

.card3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContainer">
    <div class="card" onclick="function()">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/enter--v2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/exit.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="card3">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/search--v2.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the above your total snippet ? There is no `JS` code here that you're running `onclick` of divs. The first  div's `onclick="function()"` isn't right as well.

Comment: named the function and added an alert statement, works fine

Comment: I didn't include the function cause that's where it navigates to does not matter. When you said the first divs onclick isn't right what did you mean by that?@lakshya thakur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have onclick function I think you missed javascript code well it working fine when you clicked on div

see code example

```js
function myfunction()
{
alert("clicked");
}
```

```css
#sidebarContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  height: calc(99% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
}

.card2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 82%;
}

.card3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContainer">
    <div class="card" onclick="myfunction()">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/enter--v2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/exit.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="card3">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/search--v2.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah, You are right. A different function was screwing up my div elements. 8 hours of debugging, what can I say I just love coding:))